# TFS 2018 fails to use smartcards

Tags: tfs

I am currently setting up TFS 2018 on premise. We also are in the process of moving to a new domain. The users are in the old domain and the new TFS is in the other domain. When I go to the TFS url, i get prompted to select my cert or user name and password. When i use username and password it works just fine. When i select my cert that my user account in the new domain has i get prompted for my pin 3 times and then it says access denied.

is there something that has to be done in IIS to allow the site to leverage certificates or will that not work and my users will have to have username and password?

This is my first time setting this up and Im not finding alot of documentation around the authentication methods for TFS mainly around smartcards. TFS is setup for windows authentication.

Comment: Is there a trust relationship between your domains?

Comment: no these are independent of each other.

Comment: How do you set up smartcard? Is this link helpful: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732116(v=ws.11).aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, TFS must exist in the same domain as your users, or there must be a trust relationship between the domains.

There is [some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253081(v=vs.80).aspx) on the subject although it's very old.

Comment: I brought up the trust and I was told it couldn't happen. I will read over the link you provided and see if it helps the case.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I see why they need the trust now.